# SaveChanges() only affects one row

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, datacontext, savechanges

I want to delete some records and I tried using the following code:

```
if (objDetail != null) 
{
    objContext.DetailVouchers.RemoveRange(
        objContext.DetailVouchers.Where(t => t.REFNO == strRefNo));
    objContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it only deleted the last record and not all of them.

My Context Class is

```
class MainContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MainVoucher>().ToTable("TBL_ACC_VOUCHER_MAIN");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MainVoucher>().HasKey(t => new { t.REFNO });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DetailVoucher>().ToTable("TBL_ACC_VOUCHER_DETAIL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DetailVoucher>().HasKey(t => new { t.REFNO });
}
}
```

and create context class object like

```
MainContext objContext = new MainContext();
```

Comment: How many `DetailVoucher` records can match a single `REFNO`? According to your model setup (`Entity<DetailVoucher>().HasKey(t => t => new { t.REFNO })`, zero or one.

Comment: Its show 2  records but it deleted only last one

Comment: That's the problem then. According to the model **configuration**, `DetailVoucher.REFNO` is **unique**.

Comment: I am using Master Detail Tables so using the REFNO as common in bother tables and REFNO is primary key in TBL_ACC_VOUCHER_MAIN and using same REFNO as foreign key in TBL_ACC_VOUCHER_DETAIL

Comment: If it's a foreign key, then you should not lie EF that it's a PK (see my first comment, `HasKey` part). `HasKey` means primary key. The last line in your `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: IF i did not use haskey then i get error that no has key, then how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your list of items to delete before using RemoveRange.
try reza's solution with ToList() on the first line :

```
var items = objContext.DetailVouchers.Where(t => t.REFNO == strRefNo).ToList();
objContext.DetailVouchers.RemoveRange(items);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I did but same result

Comment: ok, does it works when you use a loop instead of RemoveRange ?

Comment: No it did not. Only last record deleted

Comment: Ivan already gave you the solution : your problem is your definition of hasKey ofDetailVoucher. the key should be the primary key, not the foreign key of master. Could you add the SQL script of your 2 tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.**[EDIT]**

```
var items = objContext.DetailVouchers.Where(t => t.REFNO == strRefNo);
objContext.DetailVouchers.RemoveRange(items);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I already tried this but it commit only one record and even if i insert multiple rows and apply savechanges() then it commit only last row nad discarded all other rows

Comment: Still same issue. I am getting all records but it affects last record only

Comment: Is there any foreign key relation. can you share your table design?

Comment: No Foreign key relation